# how to call angularjs function which is appended in div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter, angularjs-controller, angularjs-compile

```
$scope.showtbleoption =  function(id)
{
    console.log(id);
    $("#showoption").empty();
    $("#showoption").append('<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="editrc(id)">');
};
```

how to call editrc() function in angularjs controller ?

Comment: Create function using scope variable inside controller. $scope.editrc = function(id){};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending raw DOM with jQuery would make angular directive compile. You have to use `$compile` service, by which you will be `$compile` that DOM first & then inject that DOM in DOM tree. `$compile` is API function(returns function) which ask for DOM, then you can again call that function by passing `$scope` to evaluate against particular `context`. `$compile` API method will take care of compiling all directives on DOM & update `bindings`.

In below case `id` value wouldn't be available inside `$scope` directly, you could either store it in a scope variable or pass it by string concatenation.

```
var compiledDom=$compile('<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="editrc('+id+')">')($scope);
$("#showoption").append(compiledDom);
```

Comment: @Anil you could accept and upvote the answer, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending using jQuery, use `$compile` service to bind it to dom. Like this:

```
$scope.domEle = $compile('<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="editrc(id)">')
```

and in HTML call like this:

```
{{ domeEle }}
```

And in controller define editrc function like this:

```
$scope.editrc = function(val){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive to bind the html's to the template dynamically . You will however have to compile the html using $compile by doing `$compile(<html>)` . Any expressions mentioned in the compiled html could call the definitions you provide in the controller .